# How do i dynamically generate a complete reactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, dynamically-generated, auto-generate

I'm creating a system in ReactJS that allows users to fill in properties and based on these properties, a complete "web page" is generated. Before the "web page" is generated, it is customized by these properties. My goal is to make this generated web page deployable on a different web address/server. Eventually i would like to edit the deployable page after generation aswell, but this is not a must.

I was preparing for this project so i have not set up anything yet. I was thinking about using StoryBook but it only renders components and doesn't "generate" a full deployable web app. If i could customize the create-react-app package or create a similar version it might fulfill my needs, but i am not sure if this is possible?

I expect this will be a though subject, but i was wondering it is even possible to create this with ReactJS? If so i would be happy to receive more information about this subject.

Comment: If your target is to build static web page, then there is existing tools like https://grapesjs.com/. If it is dynamic web page or js file with dynamic functionalities, then it's another story. Either way, I don't think it's about React - generating files should be a backend job; React should only serve as UI for creating and previewing result.

Comment: If you want to want to serve a React static website, you could use [gatsbyjs.org](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)